# Can this probability expression be simplified further: $\frac{s_ip_i(t)}{\sum s_jp_j(t)}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the following:

1. $p_0(t)$, $p_1(t)$, $...$, $p_n(t)$ are functions representing the relative frequencies of $n$ elements in time

   1. $0 \leq p_i(t) \leq 1,\ \forall i \in [0, n]$
   2. $\sum_i p_i(t) = 1$
2. $s_0$, $s_1$, $...$, $s_n$ are constants

   1. $0 \leq s_i \leq 1,\ \forall i \in [0, n]$
   2. $s_0 = 0$

**Can the following expression be simplified further?:**
$$\frac{s_ip_i(t)}{\sum_{j=0}^{n}s_jp_j(t)}$$

Basically, this is the ratio of the ($p_i$-weighted $s_i$ value") to the (weighted average of all $s$ values). Or in other words, the ratio of a term in a weighted average to the entire weighted average.

Ideally I would be able to simplify the expression to a constant (e.g., in terms of $s$ values alone), or, if not, to some other expression that only includes $s_i$'s and $p_i$'s.

===============

Edit: Motivation for question:

I am ultimately trying to evaluate the following:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \int_{p_0(t=0)=p_{0}^{(0)}}^{p_0(t=\infty)=1} \frac{s_ip_i(t)}{\sum_{j=0}^{n}s_jp_j(t)} \frac{dp_0}{p_0}$$

Furthermore, I am trying to prove that the above sum of integrals is equal to $-ln(p_0)$. (This can be shown fairly easily for $n=2$ because there is only one non-zero $s_ip_i$ term in that case, but I want to prove this holds for any $n$).

===============

Edit 2: Derivation of above integral:

Beginning with this integral

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} s_ip_i(t)dt $$

and given the following

$$\frac{dp_0}{dt} = p_0(t)\sum_{j=0}^{n}s_jp_j(t) $$
$$dt = \frac{dp_0}{p_0(t)\sum_{j=0}^{n}s_jp_j(t)} $$

the original integral becomes 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\int_{p_0(t=0)}^{p_0(t=\infty)} s_ip_i(t)\frac{dp_0}{p_0(t)\sum_{j=0}^{n}s_jp_j(t)}$$

It is known that $p_0(t=\infty) = 1$ , and introducing the simplified notation for the initial value of $p_0(t=0) = p_0^{(0)}$, we can enter these as endpoints to this integral. And with rearrangement of terms within the integral, we get the following integral, which is the same as the one in the original edit above.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \int_{p_{0}^{(0)}}^{1} \frac{s_ip_i(t)}{\sum_{j=0}^{n}s_jp_j(t)} \frac{dp_0}{p_0(t)}$$

Comment: It can't be simplified and you have even named the reason why is that so: this is just the weighted average.

Comment: @Santiago The denominator is the weighted average of s values, yes. But the numerator is another term. Is there no relationship between a term that contributes a weighted average and the total weighted average that can be used for simplification or rearrangement?

Comment: I think that is the simplest one, and it is simpe enough, so we dont need to simplify any further

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki If it is not possible to simplify further that is one thing, but calling it "simple enough" is subjective. In order for me to move forward analytically with an integration that includes this expression, the above expression would need to be simplified to a constant or only depend on i.

Comment: Yes, there is always the "stupid" simplification of starting the sum at index $j=1$ instead of $j=0$ (since $s_0=0$). :P

Comment: ah okay, my apology to say such things. What kind of integral do you need to solve? Are you sure you have to 'eliminate' index $j$ to solve that? Because in some cases, we can consider the denominator as a constant, since we already 'exhaust' all the possibilities

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki No problem. I have added information about the motivating integral to the end of my question. Perhaps that will show a path forward!

Comment: $p_0=p_0(t)$ right? and what is the meaning of $p_i(t=0)=p_i^{(0)}$ and $p_i(t=\infty)=0$ in the integral? I never saw that kind of integral before

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki I have edited my question ("Edit 2" block at end) to include clarifications for the questions in your comment.

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification, hmmmm, it really is complicated formula, but this is my opinion, since the integral is respect to $p_0(t)$, does it mean you can consider other $p_i(t)$ as constants? I tried that, and I got the answer $-\ln p_0^{(0)}$